# How to re-project multiple raster files using loop function

Tags: r, loops

I tried to work on multiple .tif files in R. I wanted to re-project the .tif files. While working on it I executed the following code.

```
#convert into raster and reproject
mylist <- list.files(path='mydir', pattern = "*.tif$")
fname <- substr(mylist, 1,20)
fn <- paste0('prj',fname, '.tif')
newproj <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
for (i in 1:4){
  temprast <- raster(mylist[i])
  prj<-projectRaster(temprast, crs=newproj, method = 'bilinear')
  writeRaster(prj, filename = fn, format='GTiff', overwrite=T)
}
```

After running the code I got the following error

```
Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.
In addition: There were 20 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Warning messages:
1: In if (filename == "") { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (!file.exists(dirname(filename))) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (toupper(x@file@name) == toupper(filename)) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (trim(filename) == "") { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
5: In if (!file.exists(dirname(filename))) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
6: In if (filename == "") { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
7: In if (file.exists(filename)) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
8: In if (nchar(filename) == 0) stop("empty file name") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
9: In if (x == "" | x == ".") { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
10: In if (!start %in% c("http", "ftp")) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
11: In if (fileext %in% c(".GRD", ".GRI")) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
12: In if (!file.exists(x)) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
13: In if ((fileext %in% c(".HE5", ".NC", ".NCF", ".NC4",  ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
14: In if (fileext == ".GRD") { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
15: In if (fileext == ".BIG" | fileext == ".BRD") { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
16: In if (fileext %in% c(".BIN")) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
17: In if (fileext == ".DOC") { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
18: In if (fileext %in% c(".SGRD", ".SDAT")) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
19: In if (nchar(filename) == 0) stop("empty file name") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
20: In if (!file.exists(x)) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Can anybody help me in this regard?
Thanks

Comment: Try printing out the file name before calling `raster`. Try adding `full=TRUE` to your `list.files` so it returns the *full path* and not just the name. Try looping over the length of `mylist` instead of hard-coding `1:4`. Try some basic debugging before asking here.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I got the same error after trying this idea. I added the full path name and tried loop over the length of files. It turns out the same error.

Comment: Print out `mylist[i]` in the loop before reading it in. See what it says. See which file it fails on - the first? The second? Then try running `raster("/whatever/is/printed/out.tif")` at the command line. Maybe the file is corrupted?

Comment: Logically there's nothing wrong with your code - and you should simplify it a bit more - do you get the same error if you take out everything except `mylist <-` before the loop and `temprast <-` inside the loop? As I said, the code looks fine, so it must be a path problem or a file problem, and we don't have your files...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with [mylist[i]], I guess it is converting only the first .tif layer because I found only the first layer with new name in my folder. I am attaching the tiff files with the main question for the convenience

Comment: Sorry for not uploading the files. The volume is exceeding.

Comment: Do we even know what line its failing yet? Reading the raster or doing the projection? If the loop is okay then you can cut this down to two lines - reading a specific raster and then reprojecting it. The more irrelevant bits of code you can remove from an example the easier it is for us to understand where the problem might be, especially if you can't get the data to us!

Comment: I am still not able to figure it out. However, the error also appears with an additional warnings. "In addition: There were 20 warnings (use warnings() to see them)". While I use the code 'warnings()', it shows a long list. Two of the warnings are given here. 1: In if (filename == "") { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (!file.exists(dirname(filename))) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: What line is failing? You've only got four tifs so what happens if you try running the code one line at a time on each file manually? You should be able to reproduce your problem with *one or two lines*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warnings arise because you attempt to write to `fn`, a vector of filenames instead of to `fn[i]`, a single filename. This means that you write to the first element, `fn[1]`, four times. It is unclear to me, where the error message came from, but I expect it will go away too.

Below is a cleaned up version. I changed `mylist` to `ff`, as `mylist` is a bad name as it is not a "list" in the `R` sense (`list.files` returns a character vector). Also  the `*` was meaningless. And I am using a more generic approach than `substr( , 1,20)`. Furthermore, it should be more efficient to write to file in `projectRaster`, instead of doing that in a separate step with `writeRaster`.

```
ff <- list.files(path='mydir', pattern = "\\.tif$")
fn <- gsub("\\.tif$", "_prj.tif", ff)
newproj <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

for (i in 1:4){
    r <- raster(ff[i])
    prj <- projectRaster(r, crs=newproj, method = 'bilinear', filename = fn[i], overwrite=TRUE)
}
```

If the rasters have the same extent and resolution, you can also do:

```
ff <- list.files(path='mydir', pattern = "\\.tif$")
s <- stack(ff)
newproj <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
prj <- projectRaster(s, crs=newproj, method ='bilinear', filename='prj.tif')
```

Comment: Thank you @RobertH. It works well. Thank you very much.